# Print folders names character count

Tags: terminal, command, wc

I am trying to use `find . -type d -print | wc -m` where `-m` or `--chars` would print the character counts of the folder names.

Take following screen shot as example, the character count for **tempFolder** + **tempFolder** + **dingdongFolder** is only **34**, and event counting the slashes and dots is still **40**. Why the command print out **43** characters? Where are the 3 extra characters come from?

[image]

Comment: Maybe counting newlines as a character?

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type d -print | tr -d '\n' | wc -m
```

`tr` will delete all newline characters and `wc` will count number you want.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently trailing newlines are counted as a character also.

Suppose you want the character count per directory, you can do

```
$ find -type d -exec bash -c 'echo -n $0 | wc -m' {} \; 
1
12
27
```

Which adds up to the 40 that you are looking for. Note that the `echo -n` removes the trailing newlines.

Summing these three is also possible.

```
$ find -type d -exec bash -c 'echo -n $0 | wc -m' {} \; | awk '{S+=$1} END  {print(S)}'
40
```

Comment: Btw, you can write just `bash -c 'echo -n {} | wc -m'`.

Comment: @rush You're right. For some reason it didn't work when I tried it, but apparently there was something wrong.

Comment: In a directory which contains 1369 sub directories, this answer was ***extremely*** slow. Here is a relative *real*, *user*, *sys* time comparison for 3 answers by: `Peter.O : Rush  :  Bernhard` ... real `1.00 : 1.01 : 193.36`, user `1.00 : 1.26 : 702.53`, sys  `1.00 : 1.01 : 109.76`...  The fastest times (for 100 itterations) were: *real 3.699* **,** *user 1.120* **,** *sys 1.120*

Answer (score 1):

Set a bash/ksh/zsh array `ct` to the output of `wc -lm`, then use shell arithmetic.

```
ct=($(find . -type d -print |wc -lm)); echo $((ct[1]-ct[0]))
```

Or use field splitting and positional parameters:

```
set $(find . -type d -print |wc -lm); echo $(($2 - $1))
```